# Pass Type dynamically to <T>

Tags: c#, generics, list

See i have a situation like this...

```
object myRoledata  = List<Roles>() --> (some list or Ienumerable type)
```

Now i have a generic method which creates an XML object from `List<T>` -
Something like this..

```
public string GetXML<T>(object listdata)  
{  
    List<T> objLists = (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(listData, typeof(List<T>));  
    foreach(var obj in listdata)   
    {  
        //logic to create xml  
    }  
}
```

Now in order to run this method I have to do like this:

```
string xml = GetXML<Roles>(myRoledata);
```

Now i dont know what `Type` may come to me to be passed to `GetXML` method. I have a method which will call `GetXML` for different `Type`s e.g. `Roles`, `Users` etc

now i can get the `Type` within the `List<>` like this

```
Type genericType = obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

but cannot pass it like this

```
string xml = GetXML<genericType>(myRoledata);
```

Is there anyway in which i can pass any `genericTypes` to `GetXML` method?

Comment: You probably want to make it clear in the question whether the (possibly multiple) types of T are unknown at compile time or not.
If they are known then Ulrik's answer makes sense, i.e. stop casting and force the argument type (perhaps with several overloads). If it is not known you must use reflection, in some form, and Marks answer shows thesimplest and likely best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem you probably want to *avoid* solving.  It *is* possible, via reflection, to call methods dynamically without statically resolving them - but it kind of defeats the whole point of the type-annotations.

Either do this:

```
public string GetXML(IEnumerable listdata) {  
    foreach(object obj in listdata)   
        //logic to create xml  
}
```

... which you now can call with any `IEnumerable`, or write it the "modern" way as:

```
public string GetXML(IEnumerable<object> listdata) {  
    foreach(object obj in listdata)   
        //logic to create xml  
}
```

... which you can call with any `IEnumerable` via `GetXML(someEnumerable.Cast<object>())` and in C# 4.0 even directly by covariance.

If you need the type of an element runtime, you can get it using `.GetType()` on each element, or you can just pass it in as a parameter (and provide an override for backwards-compatibility):

```
public string GetXML(Type elementType, IEnumerable<object> listdata) {  
    foreach(object obj in listdata)   
        //logic to create xml  
}

public string GetXML<T>(IEnumerable<T> listdata) {
    return GetXML(typeof(T),listdata.Cast<object>());
}
```

Incidentally, if you're constructing XML, a string is probably a less robust return-type choice: if possible, you could work with something like an `XElement` instead - and get xml-validity guarantee's to boot.

Comment: Actually, I'd advise against using `IEnumerable<object>` directly, atleast till C# 4.0; it likely won't do what you want it to, because of the lack of variance in type parameters. `IEnumerable` is more than usable.

Comment: Well, specifically for IEnumerable, covariance is less of an issue due to the Linq `.Cast<>` operator.  If you want to call a method with an `IEnumerable<object>` parameter and you have an `IEnumerable<T> myEnum` with some `T != object`, you can just do `myEnum.Cast<object>()` with little loss in readability and speed.  The stylistic disadvantage of the non-generic `IEnumerable` is the lack of explicit `IDisposable` support, the fact that `System.Collections` is not in the default set of usings that VS.NET adds to new files, and that it's a less common idiom.

Comment: In any case, thanks for the comment - non-generic `IEnumerable` is a fine choice too.

Answer (score 8):

To do that, you need to use reflection;

```
typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("GetXML").MakeGenericMethod(genericType)
         .Invoke(inst, new object[] {myRoleData});
```

where `inst` is `null` if it is a static method, `this` for the current instance (in which case you can also use `GetType()` instead of `typeof(SomeClass)`), or the target object otherwise.

Comment: But isn't this fundamentally wrong? By invoking the method this way, there is really no reason to use generics at all, because you throw away the type checks, and get all your errors at runtime.

Comment: My intpretation of the question is that they wanted to decouple it from generics. If that interpretation is incorrect, then your approach is clearly more appropriate. It depends on the scenario ;-p

Comment: what if the class is static?

Comment: @demodave then the inst is null

Answer (score 7):

Since you cast your listdata parameter as a List< T> in the first line of your method, why don't you just change the method signature to

```
public string GetXML<T>(List<T> listdata)
```

That way, you don't have to use reflection to get the generic arguments.

EDIT: I see that you need to be able to accept IEnumerable collections, and not just lists. So, consider changing your method signature to

```
public string GetXML<T>(IEnumerable<T> listdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your situation, but is it possible to rewrite your function as:

```
public string GetXML<T>(IEnumerable<T> listdata)  
{  
    foreach(var obj in listdata)   
    {  
        //logic to create xml  
    }  
}
```

Then it can be called as:

```
List<Role> myList;
GetXML(myList);
```

You can add type parameters as far back as needed to support it, till you get to somewhere that does know what the solid type is.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but you are using the wrong method. Have a look at Type.MakeGenericType or MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod. It will take a few more lines than your example, but it should be simple to solve.

GetGenericArguments() can be used to get the Roles type from a List. It's the differnt way around.

Btw: Looks like your implementing some kind of XML serialization. Make sure you check existing classes, before reinventing the wheel. ;-)