# How do I dynamically pass in a Type for <T>

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass Type dynamically to <T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292480/pass-type-dynamically-to-t)

How would I do something like the below?
**historyType** is not a recognized type in Adapt.

```
Type historyType = Type.GetType("Domain.MainBoundedContext.CALMModule.Aggregates.LocationAgg." + modifiedEntry.GetType().Name + "History");

ServiceLocationHistory history = adapter.Adapt<ServiceLocation, historyType>(modifiedEntry as ServiceLocation);
historyRepository.Add(history);
```

Edit:
I ended up doing this:

```
ServiceLocationHistory history = adapter.GetType()
                                    .GetMethod("Adapt", new Type[] { typeof(ServiceLocation) })
                                    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ServiceLocation), typeof(ServiceLocationHistory))
                                    .Invoke(adapter, new object[] { modifiedEntry as ServiceLocation })
                                     as ServiceLocationHistory;
```

Comment: Note that the duplicate question contains both "why you should not do that" as well as "how to do it if I need to" by Marc Gravell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not be an option for you, but you can always use a DynamicMethod and emit IL that creates your type and returns a `ServiceLocationHistory`. I often do this instead of hacky reflection tricks, and it is almost always faster.

Otherwise, with reflection you can do:

```
ServiceLocationHistory history = adapter.GetType()
                                        .GetMethod("Adapt")
                                        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ServiceLocation), historyType)
                                        .Invoke(adapter, new [] {modifiedEntry})
                                         as ServiceLocationHistory;
```